# Repository values in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I was trying to switch CircleCI to Github Actions for one of my private repository.

But I had an issue with accessing repository values in my python code. When I set "secret" via GitHub pages it works perfectly, but "variables" are not working for me at all. I expected that it was a stupid issue, but I am unable to find it out anywhere.

Let's have a simple run-tests.yml:

```
  name: Run tests
  on: push

  jobs:
    execute_tests:
        name: Install requirements and execute tests
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            - name: ...
              run: ...
            - name: Execute tests
              env:
                DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: sms.settings
                SMS_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.SMS_PASSWORD}}
                SMS_USERNAME: ${{env.SMS_USERNAME}}
              run:
                pytest -vs
```

When I list *os.environ* the `SMS_USERNAME` is defined but it has empty string inside. When I change `env.*` to `secrets.*` (and replace env variable with secret) it works as expected. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I was copying the names of the variable to prevent typo issues. There are no special characters inside `SMS_USERNAME` (just `[a-z]+`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new [`vars.VARIABLE_NAME` context to reference variables defined in the repository settings](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values).

```
            - name: Execute tests
              env:
                DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: sms.settings
                SMS_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.SMS_PASSWORD}}
                SMS_USERNAME: ${{vars.SMS_USERNAME}}
              run:
                pytest -vs
```

For clarity, the `env` variables work for all [environment variables that are set either at the workflow, job or step level using the `env:` block](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow). And the [environment variables that were set using the special workflow command](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).